# Connect to en /ext host of Fortinet VPN with Ubuntu

Tags: vpn, ipsec, fortinet

I have used openfrotivpn many times but I have never been able to properly configure such a VPN in the network manager.

Unfortunately, now I have to connect to host [some ip]/ext (e.x. 192.168.10.10/ext) and I can't do that even via cli. It is possible only by using the 'original' FortiClient.

How should I configure my network manager in this case? I want to be able to quickly connect with this VPN just like selecting a wi-fi network.

When I try to connect with it using cli, then openfortivpn throws an error.

```ini
# vpn.cfg
host=192.168.10.10/ext
port=443
username=me
password=mypass
thrusted-cert=mytrhustedcert
```

```
$ sudo openfortivpn -c vpn.cfg 
ERROR:  getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
INFO:   Closed connection to gateway.
ERROR:  connect: Connection refused
INFO:   Could not log out.
```

Additionally in FortiClient GUI, I have selected the `Do not Warn Invalid Server Certificate` option.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is connecting to a specific realm, in your case `ext`

Add to your configuration `realm = ext` or run the `openfortivpn` utility with the `--realm ext` flag.

Answer (score -1):

Similar problems with an URL as a host. I read some answers and the solution was put an IP instead the URL

Comment: I meant, "/ext" probably don't work

Comment: Nope. I've to use FortiClient app :/